# How to draw edges as 3D arcs on a geographic map using python?

Tags: python, matplotlib-basemap, network-analysis

I want to create a network map similar to

[image]

in python. So far I am able to draw it on 2D. The density of edges is making the graph untidy. Plotting the edges in 3-D would enhance the beauty and make it more appealing. 
Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In principle, what you want to do is possible with `Basemap`. You can draw a `Basemap` in a 3D axis following [this tutorial](http://basemaptutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/basemap3d.html) and then just plot your arcs on top of that. However, if you want to colour different countries the way your example figure implies, you have to start dealing with `shapefiles` (see for instance [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50965764/2454357) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48062299/2454357)). Anyway, below an example code that plots the Basemap and the arcs in a 3D plot. The part that plots the Basemap in the 3D axes is taken directly from the tutorial I linked above.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
from matplotlib.collections import PolyCollection
import numpy as np

m = Basemap()

fig = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)

ax.azim = 270
ax.elev = 50
ax.dist = 8

ax.add_collection3d(m.drawcoastlines(linewidth=0.25))
ax.add_collection3d(m.drawcountries(linewidth=0.35))

polys = []
for polygon in m.landpolygons:
    polys.append(polygon.get_coords())


lc = PolyCollection(polys, edgecolor='black',facecolor='#DDDDDD', closed=False)
ax.add_collection3d(lc)

def plot_arc(ax,p1,p2,height,N=100):
    x = np.linspace(p1[0],p2[0],N)
    y = np.linspace(p1[1],p2[1],N)
    z = (1-np.linspace(-1,1,N)**2)*height
    ax.plot(x,y,z)

plot_arc(ax,(-70,0),(80,50),1)
plot_arc(ax,(80,50),(125,-25),1)
plot_arc(ax,(125,-25),(-70,0),1)

plt.show()
```

Here the result of the example code:

[image: result of the above code]

Hope this helps.