# Parabolic connection graph using Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, visualization, geospatial

I am trying to create a connection graph using Python. I'd like a series of points across the UK converging on a target, with accentuated parabolic arcs.

I have a code attempt that is plotting straight lines at the moment. I'd like to increase the curvature of these lines with a parameter.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import geopandas as gpd
import contextily as ctx
import sympy as sm

def plot_connection(ax, start_point, end_point):
    x1, y1 = start_point[0], start_point[1]
    x3, y3 = end_point[0], end_point[1]
    
    x2 = (x1 + x3) / 2
    y2 = (y1 + y3) / 2
    
    x = np.array([x1, x2, x3])
    y = np.array([y1, y2, y3])

    a, b, c = sm.symbols('a b c', real=True)
    
    eq1 = sm.Eq((x[0]**2) * a + x[0] * b + c, y[0])
    eq2 = sm.Eq((x[1]**2) * a + x[1] * b + c, y[1])
    eq3 = sm.Eq((x[2]**2) * a + x[2] * b + c, y[2])

    sol = sm.solve([eq1, eq2, eq3], (a, b, c))

    def f(x):
        return sol[a] * (x**2) + sol[b] * x + sol[c]

    col = np.tan(np.linspace(-1, 1, 1500))
    plt.scatter(np.linspace(x[0], x[-1], 1500), f(np.linspace(x[0], x[-1], 1500)),
                c=col, zorder=-3, cmap='gray', s=0.005, alpha=0.6)

#london point 1, point 2
target = (-251467.639557, 7014473.211674)
london = (-23236.856599, 6713617.068344)
glasgow = (-472686.582916, 7534245.004013)
leeds = (-173664.928264, 7133714.975799)
brighton = (-14675.909431, 6599267.274029)
darmstadt = (88791.533909, 6672007.566294)
manchester = (-251095.637917, 7069851.838667)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 15))

#make a df of points across the uk
import pandas as pd

plot_connection(ax, target, london)
plot_connection(ax, target, glasgow)
plot_connection(ax, target, leeds)
plot_connection(ax, target, brighton)
plot_connection(ax, target, darmstadt)
plot_connection(ax, target, manchester)

#add xlim ylim over uk
# ax.set_xlim(-520000, 175000)
# ax.set_ylim(6500000, 8200000)

ctx.add_basemap(ax, source=ctx.providers.CartoDB.PositronNoLabels, zorder=-4, crs='EPSG:3857')
ax.axis('off')
plt.tight_layout()
```

Currently looks like:

[image]

I'd like a figure with arcs similar to this, working on the scale of within the UK: [image]

Comment: Wouldn't you be better using a 3-d plot? Your parabolas could be drawn using Lagrange interpolation passing through start point and end point on the surface and an intermediate point at a height proportional to the distance between start and end. (BTW, you appear to have put Darmstadt in Burnley; it's actually in Germany!)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to draw edges as 3D arcs on a geographic map using python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51455790/how-to-draw-edges-as-3d-arcs-on-a-geographic-map-using-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply create an arc and add it to your line from two points to create a parabolic curve on the map. The `distance` and `arc_ratio` variables are used to make the curve better.

```py
def plot_connection(ax, start_point, end_point):
    
    x = np.linspace(start_point[0], end_point[0], 1500)
    y = np.linspace(start_point[1], end_point[1], 1500)
    distance = np.sqrt((start_point[0]-end_point[0])**2+(start_point[1]-end_point[1])**2)

    arc_ratio = 0.5 # 0 -> straight line; higher ratio creates bigger curve
    arc = (1-np.linspace(-1, 1, 1500)**2) * distance * arc_ratio
    y += arc

    col = np.tan(np.linspace(-1, 1, 1500))
    plt.scatter(x, y, c=col, zorder=-3, cmap='gray', s=0.005, alpha=0.6)
```

The result:

[image]